# Add a text file as a resource in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, webview2

I am creating a WebView2 app (WPF using C#) and I want to have a index.html file as a resource.
The idea is that when I create a project, a new folder is created.
This folder will contain an index.html file for the WebView control to load.
The index.html file then points to project specific data as relative paths.

I would like to have a file embedded in my resources that I can use at runtime like this

```
`void newProject()
{
   string strHTML = /** code to read from resource file **/
   createFile(projDir + "\\index.html") /** code to create a new file **/
   /** code to write strHTML string to new index.html file **/
} 
`
```

I know I can create a static string to do this, but editing is easier if I have the resource as a file.

Thanks in advance.

D

Update:
I put the file into the resources. Then, I added this code

```
var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
String[] resources = assem.GetManifestResourceNames();
html = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("index.html")
```

The resources string array always has two elements regardless of what I have in my resources file.
"WebView2Testing.g.resources"
"WebView2Testing.Properties.Resources.resources"
which has nothing to do with my file.
GetManifestResourceStream("index.html") returns null.

FYI I am using .net6 and WPF Windows app.

Any more ideas?

Comment: You can add a file to a project and set it as an embedded resource. Within your code, you can use [`GetManifestResourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=net-7.0) to read the resource.

Comment: Jonathan, your response helped but I can't see the file in the resources using the GetManifestResourceStream. See my update above

Comment: Don't add the file to resources. Add the file to the project and in the properties for the file change the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. The name will start with the `RootNamespace` of the project. If your project's `RootNamespace` is "WebView2Testing", then the name is "WebView2Testing.index.html".

Comment: Yup, that is what was missing. I will post a complete solution with code later in case someone else can benefit from this. Thanks Jonathan